# Calculus Help on Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I am looking at this alternate definition for finding limits. I have attached a link which will take you to the new definition and an example. It will also show you the first 2 exercises I have to complete. I am lost on how to start them and would appreciate any guidance I can get. I got the first one, but what I am having trouble with is choosing 2 sequences. I thought about selecting 1/2(pi)n and 1/2(pi)n+1/2(pi). I am not sure if it is correct or not. This is from exercise 3.

LINK: http://tinypic.com/r/167qsmq/9

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, *and what your thoughts on it are;* this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you get started.

One particular sequence that you can choose is to let $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$. can you evaluate the limit if it exists? what is it equal to?

Now can you figure out another sequence such that the limit go to another value? for example $1$ (or possibly $-1$ or other values?)

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a logical flaw in the def'n in the link. It says "$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$  if for all sequences $(a_n)_n $ in  dom$(f)$ converging to $a$..."(etc.). The "if" should be "if and only if."  This matters in the very next sentence, concerning non-convergence, where the "only if" part is implicitly  assumed. A hidden assumption can be disastrous, although not here, mainly because it is part of a def'n. But I would not want it in a textbook.
2. If $f(x)=\sin (1/x)$ for $x\ne 0,$ consider $x_{2 n}=1/(2 \pi n)$ and $x_{2 n-1}=1/(2 \pi n+\pi/2)$ for $n\in N.$ Then $(x_n)_n$ converges to $0$ but $f(x_{2 n})=0$ and $f(x_{2 n-1})=1.$ So $(\;f(x_n)\;)_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Regarding 1.: the linked image gives a *definition*: not need for an "iff" in that case. "We say that $X$ is a key if $X$ is a thing that unlocks some door." Regarding 2. : given that the OP hasn't shown much (any) of her/his work, providing only a hint and keeping the last sentence as a "spoiler" may be better?